# Calculate profit / loss of machine learning algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, machine-learning

The following project is a javascript project.

In our game there is a racetrack where the algorithm has the choice to turn left or right, or drive straight ahead.
If we give the algorithm the right weight, it will move 100% correctly. Now my question is: how do we do it exactly with the error calculation? Finally, the algorithm should approach the optimum itself.
Our current approach:

Weights:

```
let leftWeight = [1.0, -1.0, -1.0];
let stayWeight = [-1.0, 1.0, -1.0];
let rightWeight = [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0];
```

stored in a weights[].
Calculation of upcoming move:

```
leftMove = (leftSensor * weights[0][0]) + (staySensor * weights[1][0]) + (rightSensor* weights[2][0]);
stayMove = (leftSensor * weights[0][1]) + (staySensor * weights[1][1]) + (rightSensor* weights[2][1]);
rightMove = (leftSensor * weights[0][2]) + (staySensor * weights[1][2]) + (rightSensor* weights[2][2]);
```

where the sensor is storing the information 'road' or !'road'.
With the previous values it works 100% correct, but we want it to get to this state by itself. Therefore we have a 'win/loss move handler' which will consider if it was a good / bad move.
But at this point, we don't know how to continue.
Changing things here leads to the fact that the direction + 'Move' values become NaN or sth.
TLDR; 
 We don't know how to evaluate the loss / how to change values if the algorithm did a wrong move.
Any suggesstion is welcomed

If any information is missing to understand the problem, just let me know.

Thank you ;)

Edit:
Road(array)
|!R| |!R| |!R| |R| |!R|
|!R| |!R| |!R| |R| |!R|
|!R| |!R| |R| |R| |!R|
|!R| |!R| |R| |!R| |!R|

Comment: How does your road look like?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the concept of Reinforcement Learning: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning

Comment: hi, I have edited my question ;)